# How does the :: operator work in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, syntax, constants

I am new to Ruby and am confused by the `::` operator. Why does the following code output *2, 3, 4, 5, 1* and not just output *1*? Thanks!

```
class C
  a = 5
  module M
    a = 4
    module N
      a = 3
      class D
        a = 2
        def show_a
          a = 1
          puts a
        end
        puts a
      end
      puts a
    end
    puts a
  end
  puts a
end



d = C::M::N::D.new
d.show_a
```

Comment: Because you call `puts` 5 times?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you remove the last line, you will see that you will get `5, 4, 3, 2`. The reason is that the body of classes and modules is just regular code (unlike in some other languages). Therefore, those print statements will be executed when the classes/modules are getting parsed.

As to how `::` works - it just lets you move around the scopes. `::A` will reference the `A` in the main scope. Just `A` will refer to `A` in the current scope. `A::B` will refer to the `B`, that is inside the `A`, that is inside the current scope.